# C# .NET CORE: cancell other tasks if one returned some kind of result

Tags: c#, multitasking, .net-core-2.2

How to cancel all tasks, if one of them return i.e. false (bool) result?
Is it possible to identify which task returned a result?

```
class Program
    {
        private static Random _rnd = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasksCounter = _rnd.Next(4, 7);
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var tasks = new Task<bool>[tasksCounter];
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = CreateTask(cts); 
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting..");
            Task.WaitAny(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Task<bool> CreateTask(CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskAction, cts.Token).Unwrap();
        }

        private static async Task<bool> TaskAction()
        {
            var delay = _rnd.Next(2, 5);
            await Task.Delay(delay * 1000);
            var taskResult = _rnd.Next(10) < 4;
            return await Task.FromResult(taskResult);
        }
    }
```

I tried to use Task.WaitAll, Task.WaitAny etc, but none of these methods provide useful (in my case) functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
As @ckuri stated in the comments, it would be easier to leverage the already existing properties of `Task` instead of writing a custom result class. Adjusted my answer accordingly.

One solution would be to check for the result in the `CreateTask()` method and pass a `CancellationToken` into your `TaskAction()` method:

```
private static Task<bool> CreateTask(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var result = await TaskAction(cts.Token);

        // If result is false, cancel all tasks
        if (!result)
            cts.Cancel();

        return result;
    });
}

private static async Task<bool> TaskAction(CancellationToken token)
{
    // Check for cancellation
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var delay = Rnd.Next(2, 5);
    // Pass the cancellation token to Task.Delay()
    await Task.Delay(delay * 1000, token);

    var taskResult = Rnd.Next(10) < 4;

    // Check for cancellation
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    return taskResult;
}
```

Now you can do something like this in your `Main` method to receive all tasks which did not get cancelled:

```
try
{
    // Wait for all tasks inside a try catch block because `WhenAll` throws a `AggregationException` 
    // containing a `TaskCanceledException`, if the token gets canceled
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
} 
catch { }

var tasksWithResult = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCanceled).ToList();
```

Comment: A Task already has Result and IsCanceled properties. There is no need to reimplement this. Instead of the `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) { … }` a simple `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` would do the same job and would make the try-catch unnecessary. This would reduce your needlessly complex `TaskAction` method to 5 lines.

Comment: @ckuri Thank you for the hint, adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an interpreter on hand, so excuse any mistakes. Your Task needs access to the token if you want to cancel all tasks from the task itself. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-3.0 for an example. I.e. pass it as an argument to the task so one task can cancel the other tasks.

```
    private static async Task<bool> TaskAction(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        var delay = _rnd.Next(2, 5);
        await Task.Delay(delay * 1000);
        var taskResult = _rnd.Next(10) < 4;
        if (!taskResult)
           cts.Cancel()
        return await Task.FromResult(taskResult);
    }
```

Just be sure to capture the `AggregateException` and check if one of the inner excepts is an `TaskCanceledException`.

Comment: You set the CancellationTokens into the cancelled state, but you are never doing something with tokens. I guess you forgot to provide the Task.Delay with the CancellationToken?